# WPF: How to find space available for Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, space

I'm using WPF shapes to create Hexagons (for a game map) on a Canvas. After some playing around with ScrollViewer, I've decided to implement the scrolling and zoom of the map myself rather than using WPF functionality, just using WPF to get the events for mouse wheel, arrow keys etc. I'm placing the (Hex Map) Canvas as the last child inside a Dock Panel so it will get all the available remaining space. The Dock Panel will be set to be the content of the Main Window. But I want to find out how big the Canvas can be before I put any Children on the Canvas so that I can centre the screen over the Hex I want and only add the Shapes (Hexs) that can actually be seen. When zoomed out, a long way I will remove Polygons altogether and use another method of rendering and when zoomed in a long way I will add more details.

Is there any neat way of getting the available space? The only way that I can think of that will hopefully work is to get the current dimensions of the windows and subtract the dimensions of the outer elements of the Dock Panel, but that feels rather messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of `Canvas` to determine size available to it. Be sure that `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` are set to `Stretch`.

Comment: Ah I've managed to set the alignments to Stretch in Code, but I don't think it makes any difference as that's the default values anyway. Its still giving me a size of 0;

Comment: When you want to get a size, are you sure that Canvas already arranged? Check IsMeasureValid and IsArrangeValid properties. Have a look at the SizeChanged event to react whenever ActualWidth and ActualHeight are changing.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake! I had an extra Grid in my Stack Panel which was messing things up. Although I'm still not sure why the Actual Width and Height were shown as 0 and remained at 0, because it was rendering the Hexs. I now just create the Canvas without Children in the Window Constructor and then call the OnRender event to draw on the Canvas